# How to initiate a Standard Javascript Callback in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I initiate this callback on Vue.js on page load?:

```
 lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a vue.js function on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714319/how-to-call-a-vue-js-function-on-page-load)

Comment: I have tried the ready(), as well as just adding within script tags below.

Comment: I keep getting this error: lightGallery has not initiated properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Vue's life cycle hooks is **beforeMount**,
Your code can be:

```
beforeMount(){
   lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery')); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the initialization in your `vue` component with lifecycle `hooks`:

```
Vue.component('lightGallery', function() {
  template: '<div>Place template markup here</div>',
  mounted: function() {
    $(this.$el).lightGallery(); 
  }
});
```

Then you can just use the component:

```
<lightGalleryr></lightGallery>
```

There are different lifecycle hooks Vue provide:

I have listed few are :

- **beforeCreate**: Called synchronously after the instance has just been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.
- **created**: Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this stage, the instance has finished processing the options which means the following have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods, watch/event callbacks. However, the mounting phase has not been started, and the $el property will not be available yet.
- **beforeMount**: Called right before the mounting begins: the render function is about to be called for the first time.
- **mounted**: Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el.
- **beforeUpdate**: Called when the data changes, before the virtual DOM is re-rendered and patched.
- **updated**: Called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.

You can have a look at complete list [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks).

You can choose which hook is most suitable to you and hook it to call you function like the sample code provided above.

Comment: would this apply in SSR?