# PHP API WITH VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js

I Created my API with PHP and here is the link: https://monstajams.co/streaming/rest/api/album/read.php

But anytime i put it in my Vue.js (Home.vue) file using axios No data is displayed on the front-end.

Here is my code below:

```
<ul class="ta-track-list" v-if="faqs && faqs.length">
        <li class="ta-track-card column col-2 flex-column" v-for="faq of faqs">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="artwork" role="link">
                    <span role="link" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/mymusic/assets/images/artwork/Wizkid-Soco.jpg);">

                    </span>
                        <div class="hover flex align-center justify-center">
                            <button id="webutton" class="ta-secondary play" onclick='playSong()'>
                                <i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="title white-primary-hover" role="lin">{{ faqs }}</div>  
                        <div class="username light-white-hover" role="link">{{ faq.artist }}</div>  
                        <div class="released">{{ faq.duration }}</div>
                    </div>  
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>


<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'home',
    data: () =>({
        faqs: [],
        errors: []
    }),

    created() {
        axios.get('https://monstajams.co/streaming/rest/api/album/read')
        .then(response => {
            this.faqs = response.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e)
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show us how your component data is structured?

Comment: If your vue app is on localhost, it must be CORS

Comment: Inside catch(e) - can you console.log out e?

Comment: @darklightcode My header // Headers
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: @darklightcode Doesn't look like a CORS issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/942698vlnw?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

Comment: @naija `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"` , add this too, maybe some preflight OPTIONS are sent during the request. Any aditional httpStatus, logging might help if you got any

Comment: @AlexMulchinock yes, i've just seen the headers from the request, no CORS indeed.

Comment: @naija - to ask a silly question; are you actually outputting the data in your template anywhere? Your code works (see the example link I posted above).
Can we see your template structure?

Comment: I could access the JSON from this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/epfyv9nw/ and even with your code. Are you sure `created()` gets called ? that `data` method doesn't seem to do much either ( if you plan on populating faqs ). Show us more code, the context where you are calling the request

Comment: @AlexMulchinock I have included my template code

Comment: @darklightcode I have included the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code incorrectly assumes `axios.get()` resolves to the raw response, but it actually resolves to a [response wrapper](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/a74ab87/README.md#response-schema), where the raw response is contained in a `data` subproperty of the wrapper, which coincidentally has the same name as the target property within the response.

You can either change your Axios response handler to get the inner `data` field:

```
axios.get('https://monstajams.co/streaming/rest/api/album/read')
     .then(response => {
       // this.faqs = response.data; // response.data is the raw response, but you need the array within the response (also named "data")
       this.faqs = response.data.data;
     })
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/kww8l3p91r)

Or leave your frontend alone, and update your PHP backend to send only the array in the response:

```
// FROM THIS RESPONSE:
{
  data: [/* PLAYLIST DATA */]
}

// TO THIS RESPONSE:
[/* PLAYLIST DATA */]
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not updating your data accordingly to Vue docs.

For reactive changes see this [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

In the example below i update my list before Vue is mounted so rendering can occur accordingly.

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: []
  },
  methods: {
    updateList() {

      axios.get('https://monstajams.co/streaming/rest/api/album/read')
        .then(res => {

          res.data.data.forEach(item => {

            Vue.set(vm.todos, vm.todos.length, {
              text: item.title,
              done: true
            })

          })

        })

    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.updateList()
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <span>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter please explain on how my answer was inadequate and deserved a downvote

Comment: In the `beforeMount` method i trigger `this.updateList` method that updates `todo` list before the rendering occurs. It's basically your code, i just used `beforeMount` instead of `created`, see the vue docs for additional info and this post for a quick read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714319/how-to-call-a-vue-js-function-on-page-load/40714462 , please revise your vote, stackoverflow is not about fixing your code, it's about pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm *guessing* this answer was downvoted because (1) it claims `Vue.set` is required to fix the OP's problem (*but that's not true, and the root problem is actually something else*), and (2) it drastically changes the context of the API data (from playlist to todo list), which can be confusing to readers.