# I'm writing method in vue.js, but I want it to work without clicking the button.how can I do it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I write method using store, but I want it to run every time the page is refreshed without clicking the button, how can I do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a vue.js function on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714319/how-to-call-a-vue-js-function-on-page-load)

Comment: Invoke the method from mounted(). See this doc https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html.